# Making a header image scale depending upon the screen resolution with a margin

Tags: html, css

I am currently trying to build a website, and the banner image isn't scaling within the margin that im wanting, I would rather the help in CSS but HTML would work aswell.

HTMl

```
<!-- Page Title -->

    <div>
        <header>
            <img src="../Images/Original.svg" class="logo">
        </header>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
img {
  height:auto;
  width:92.5%;
}

.logo {
  background-color:#1d2e3f;
  margin-left:50px;
  margin-right:50px;
  object-fit:cover;
}
```

Any help would be amazing, also if any clarification is required let me know
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Using **calc()** in CSS to width solve this.

Instead of using

```
width:92.5%;
```

Find the width by, Mathamatically

```
Width (100%) = 100% - margin = 100% - 100px
```

using CSS :  **`width: calc(100% - 100px);`**

```
img {
  width: calc(100% - 100px); 
}
```

**About calc() function**

> The **[`calc()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc)** CSS function lets you perform calculations when specifying CSS property values. It can be used anywhere a `<length>`, `<frequency>`, `<angle>`, `<time>`, `<percentage>`, `<number>`, or `<integer>` is allowed.

**NOTE**: **calc()** function takes a **single expression as its parameter**, with the expression's result used as the value.

**`Working Demo`**

```css
img {
  height:auto;
  width: calc(100% - 100px); 
}

.logo {
  background-color:#1d2e3f;
  margin-left:50px;
  margin-right:50px;
  object-fit:cover;
}
```

```html
<!-- Page Title -->

<div>
    <header>
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300" class="logo">
    </header>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Dont forgot [to accept answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) :).

Answer (score 0):

Simple scaled image;

**HTML**

```
 <img src='https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/abstract-dotted-banner-background_1035-18160.jpg' id='banner' alt='banner'>
```

**CSS**

```
 #banner {position:relative; float:left; width:100%; height:100%;}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/nkhjbo51/1/

If you want a margin or padding around that banner, encase it in an outer div and set the margin/padding on that outer div...

**HTML**

```
 <div id='outer'><img src='https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/abstract-dotted-banner-background_1035-18160.jpg' id='banner' alt='banner'></div>
```

**CSS**

```
 #outer {margin:20px;}
 #banner {position:relative; float:left; width:100%; height:100%;}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/40h8vqur/